# rewrite to www and rewrite directory name

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Hi I have some thing like the following, everything works perfectly until I try and add 'www' if it doesn't exist I get something like the below:

origin: http://domain.net/welcome/

Rewrite: http://www.domain.net//index.php/?request=welcome

```
php_value register_globals "on"
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /index.php?request=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.net$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.net/$1 [R=301]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php?request=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your redirect rules above the rest of your rules and add the [L] flag:

```
php_value register_globals "on"
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.net$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.net/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /index.php?request=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php?request=$1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I've already tried that, with no joy.

Comment: Still get this: http://www.domain.net//index.php/?request=welcome from the url domain.net//index.php/?request=welcome

Comment: @jhodgson4 not sure what the problem is, when I put this in an empty htaccess file in my document root it get redirected correctly